# HTTP client request timeout handling in keep-alive connections

Tags: http, keep-alive, http-pipelining

Regarding to HTTP keep-alive how request timeout should be handled on client side? For example there is a flow:

- Client sends Request1;
- Client waits for 1 minute;
- Client assumes the Request1 failed and resends it, i.e. sends new Request2 = Request1;
- Server responds with Response1 (which is response for Request1);
- Client assumes this is a response to Request2 but can handle it because Request1 = Request2;
- Client sends Request3;
- Server responds with Response2 (which is response for Request2);
- Client assumes this is a response to Request3 and fails to handle it.

I couldn't find any info in [specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8). It says how to retry if connection was closed by server but nothing about the situation when request took too long to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with ASP.NET though I'm not sure if this paradiagm is used for all HTTP pipelines. Here's what I understand:

- The response is tied to the request. In C#, there is a [`HttpContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) that facilitates this. The new request comes in on a separate thread which has no safe context of any other requests.
- When a client makes a request, (for example, via [`WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx)) the response is tied to that request.

Therefore `Request1` in your example could never be mixed up with `Request2`. The `keep-alive` that's used in the HTTP request header indicates that the underlying [TCP connection shouldn't be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20799796/1244630) so that it can be reused for other requests. As far as I understand, a single request timing out doesn't affect the underlying TCP connection; that is, even though the TCP connection is shared, the request-response mechanisms work as usual.