# Will the TCP connection be shut down after a HTTP request/response?

Tags: sockets, http, networking, tcp

HTTP is conventionally considered a stateless protocol. The browser establishes connection with the server during a request,and after the browser gets the response, the HTTP connection will be closed.


Also, HTTP is a application layer protocol. When the browser sends a request to the server or receives a response from the server, data is passed down to the next layer, then encapsulated into a transport layer protocol. 

Here is the question.
Is the TCP connection between the browser and the server closed immediately after a request/response in HTTP? Or it will keep connection for a while?

Comment: HTTP Keep-Alive was added to HTTP/1.0 already, see duplicate for an explanation.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592698/keep-alive-header-clarification) is quite helpful!